# I need to know the generic type of a list which was passed as an argument as type object in java?without iterating the list

Tags: java

```
static void test1(int x) {

    switch(x) {
    case 1 :{ ArrayList<String> list1  = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    case 2 : { ArrayList<Integer> list1  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }
    }
    ((List)list1).add((<casttype>)x); //line x
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test1(1);
}
```

in test1 the list is created according the argument passsed from main function

in line x the x argument has to be added after typecasting according to the type with the list was initialised in the switch case

Comment: `I need to know the generic type` ... no you don't.  That's the whole point of using a generic collection.

Comment: What I am saying is that proper use of a generic list is to only call methods common to the interface.  That is to say, you don't need to know what types are in there.

Comment: i get that ,but i need to know a way to find the type with which the list was created

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have edited my question is it clear now

Comment: Your code is textbook bad practice.  It isn't possible to add to a generic list, therefore you might want to consider not using generics in `test2()`.

Comment: the test1 function is not my function actually its in another class which i cant do anything about

Answer (score 1):

You can't: you've lost the information in `test1` where you assign the newly created list to a variable of the raw type `List`.

UPDATE:

Now the information is lost when you pass the list to `test2`.

Comment: @GeordinJose it will still not work: the information is lost by passing the list to `test2`.

Comment: i have changed the code now..... is it possible to get the type with which it was initialised..

Comment: @GeordinJose this would not even compile. Keep in mind that the generic type is (statically) bound to the variable `list1`, not the `ArrayList` object it refers to.